# iframe src allows all origins but still receiving Cross-Origin Errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, https

I manage the frontend of siteA and have an iframe on the page with a src pointing to a resource from siteB. This is meant to be an embeddable resource (its a video embed) used by other vendors & clients so the response headers of siteB are set to Access-Control-Allow-Origin *. And all URLs involved are https.

I have a screenshot here of the headers here from the src url in dev tools:

[image: screenshot of response headers]

However, **I’m still receiving cross-origin errors when trying to query the iframe document to check if a specific element is present**.

I’m not trying to modify any content but want to make simple UI decisions depending on the content.

To no avail I’ve tried:

- standard jQuery methods like $(‘iframe’).contents().find()
- $.get requests to retrieve the html response and see if it includes a specific string

Am I missing something? Getting over this hurdle would be a major win for our project.

Comment: I don't see the Allow-Origin in those response headers.

Comment: There is no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in that screenshot...?

Comment: "the response headers of siteB are set to Access-Control-Allow-Origin *"...are they? As pointed out above, it's not visible in your screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could apply the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header which will allow you to read ajax responses from another domain, eg:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

But this header will **NOT** allow you to access a rendered iframe from another domain due to the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). But it would allow you to make a new ajax (GET) request to the iFrame's domain and then work with the response.

This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) explores some ways that the same-origin-policy can be bypassed, some of the suggestions might help you, but it depends what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Likely because of comments made under the question and the downvote of the question. OP claims the headers are set but does not show that they are - if they are not set and he claims they are, an answer telling him to set the headers will not change the issue

Comment: Fair enough, thank you for your feedback. My answer was intended to explain why CORS will not prevent SOP in relation to iframes, a common misconception. I still hope my answer can help the OP and others.